# vb.net unique array of structures

Tags: arrays, vb.net, struct, unique

I have a structure

```
Public Structure MyRecords
    Dim record_name As String
    Dim record_surname As String
End Structure
```

and an array of structures

```
Dim Records_arr(100000) AS MyRecords
```

The array is full of data, but i want the duplicate `MyRecords` to be removed.

Duplicate means:

```
Records_arr(3).record_name = "John"
Records_arr(3).record_surname = "Doe"

Records_arr(99).record_name = "John"
Records_arr(99).record_surname = "Doe"
```

In this example i want `Records_arr(3)` or `Records_arr(99)` to be removed, or just empty the values of one of them.

I have already implemented a 2-pass scan top-to-bottom and then bottom-to-top that wipes out duplicates, but it's very very slow. There's got to be a better way?

Comment: close vote? are you serious?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Implement `IEquatable<T>` on your structure and then use LINQ's `Distinct()` function to get your goals.

Here's a sample implementation:

```
Public Structure MyRecords
    Implements IEquatable(Of MyRecords)

    Dim record_name As String
    Dim record_surname As String

    Public Function Equals1(other As MyRecords) As Boolean Implements IEquatable(Of MyRecords).Equals
        Return record_name.Equals(other.record_name) AndAlso record_surname.Equals(other.record_surname)
    End Function
End Structure
```

Now you can call `Records_arr.Distinct()` and it will return unique records of your array.

**Further Explanation**

In response to your comment, here's what's going on. Since you're using a `Structure` and not a `Class`, `MyRecords` already inherits `ValueType.Equals()` method. For value types that do not contain any reference type members, the `Equals()` method performs byte-by-byte comparison of the two objects in memory. On the other hand, if it does contain reference type members (which is your case), it uses Reflection to compare the corresponding fields of the two instance. You have two `String` fields in your structure, which are reference types and are therefore compared through Reflection. (Important to note that `String` class, although a reference type, overrides `Equals()` to provide value comparison instead of the default reference comparison). Thus even if you do not implement `IEquatable` or `IComparable` on your class, `Distinct()` will work fine using the default `ValueType.Equals()` function.

Be advised however that MSDN asks you to provide `Equals()` implementation for this kind of structures. Here's the relevant excerpt:

*Particularly if your value type contains fields that are reference types, you should override the Equals(Object) method. This can improve performance and enable you to more closely represent the meaning of equality for the type.*

You can read more about it in [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2dts52z7(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: why not just return `false` after the `else`? am i missing something here? oh wait does it return a collection?

Comment: This is `IComparable`, not `IEquatable`. The return type is integer. `IComparable` is superior in the sense that it can be used by `Distinct()` as well as `OrderBy()`, as `CompareTo()` can be used to sort objects, because it returns -1, 0 or 1 as result, not just `True`/`False`.

Comment: @Sharky: Just verified that `Distinct()` works with `IEquatable` only, not `IComparable`. Edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: created a 10 records array, 0 and 1 are the same, i'm calling `Records_arr.Distinct()` and `Records_arr(0)` and `Records_arr(1)` are still there with same values?

Comment: nevermind got it, i forgot `.toArray` well that was embarrasing >.<

Comment: it does works with `IComparable` see what i got here http://pastebin.com/fTGMPBs5 maybe you want to revert your edit?

Comment: @Sharky: See my explanation above.

Comment: why no reference to `me.`?

Comment: Which line are you talking about? Qualifying local members with `Me` is normally not needed, so you can to type `SomeMember` instead of `Me.SomeMember`.

Comment: on `return` inside `equals1`. oh ok thanks for your comment :D